# ThreeJS: How to increase and decrease segments?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

In a Cube Geometry how to increase and decrease segments?. I would change `segmentsWidth` and `segmentsHeight` parameters, to be exact.
Does anyone know if it's possible with three lib?

Comment: In a Cube Geometry. I would change segmentsWidth and segmentsHeight parameters, to be exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the number of segments in `BoxGeometry` ( previously called `CubeGeometry` ) after the geometry is created, unless of course, you write your own code to do it.

EDIT: On a related note, here is an example of using the Catmull-Clark subdivision algorithm to smooth a geometry: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_subdivision.html.